# Disjoint closed subsets are respectively included in disjoint open subsets in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space. Show that, if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint closed subsets of $M$, there exist disjoint open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $E_1 \subset U_1$ and $E_2 \subset U_2$.

Got this question in my analysis class and have been trying to figure out where to start for a week! Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the sets

$$ U_1 = \{ x \in M \, | d(x, E_2) > d(x, E_1) \}, \,\,\, U_2 = \{ x \in M \, | d(x, E_1) > d(x, E_2) \}. $$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by this?